# How to markup different product sizes with schema.org?

Tags: seo, schema.org, microformats

The product page offers two sizes for each product. For example Coca-Cola 1liter and Coca-Cola 0.5liter. Above is the productname "Coca-Cola" and beneath of that comes the "Coca-Cola" description. Is it possible to insert both sizes into the schema.org markup or do i have to choose one productsize and just ingnore the other size/price?

Comment: schema.org and microdata are not microformats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you refer to [Thing > Product](http://schema.org/Product)

Product is defined as:

> anything that is made available for sale — for example, a pair of shoes, a concert ticket, or a car.

In e-commerce world *anything that is made available for sale* is called SKU (stock-keeping unit) and product is **usually** a *container* for SKUs (I said usually, as different platforms can have different terms or data structures).

So from your description I see that your system has a **product** which is "*A bottle of Coca-Cola*" with two **SKUs**:

- **1-litter bottle of Coca-Cola**
- **0.5-litter bottle of Coca-Cola**

I would use information of the SKUs for [`schema.org` Product](http://schema.org/Product).

Some `schema.org` attributes comes from parent product (in your case *A bottle of Coca-Cola*) e.g. `url` (assuming you have two SKUs: *1-litter* and *0.5-litter* on the same page) or `description` (assuming you have generic description coming from product). But some other attributes like `weight` (or `size` / `price`) will be specific for each bottle. There is also `sku` attribute which usually refers to your SKU number.

*As a side note, you can find similar challenge when building, say, [Google Product Feed](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188494#GB), and the similar approach will work perfectly fine.*

I hope that will help.

Comment: OK, that would result in for example:
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"><span itemprop="name">Coca-Cola Bottle</span>  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><span itemprop="sku">112233</span><span itemprop="price">$5.00</span></div><div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><span itemprop="sku">112234</span><span itemprop="price">$10.00</span></div>
<span itemprop="description">Coca-Cola Bottles that taste perfect!</span></div>
But where should i insert the bottle size?

Comment: @Imi78, I would use bottle size in `weight` attribute which is of QuantitativeValues type (http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue). `Value` attibute (of QuantitativeValues type) would have `1` or `0.5` and `unitCode` would have code for `liter` (as far as I remember the code is `LTR` but I would suggest double checking that )